# Converting a normal RV to Standard Normal RV and distribution of a 3-case RV

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $ X \sim N(0,2)$ and $Y=X^2$

And let
$$
Z=
\begin{cases}
  1 & X>0 \\
  0 & X =0 \\
  -1 & X<0
\end{cases}
$$

And I would like to know the relationships between Y and Z (are they dependent, coordinated etc.

Iv'e a few questions regarding that:

1. Could it help to convert X to the standard normal form? When would one do that? if I should, how can I do that?
2. Does Z consider to be continuous or discrete? because I learned that discrete RV usually have this kind of "steps" graph, like the above Z, but on the other hand, it doesn't look countable, so I am confused about it.
3. Can I simply calculate $E[Z]$ by integrating all 3 regions and summing it? (if continuous of course).

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $Z$ can only take on three values, it is discrete. We can work out its marginal distribution as follows:
\begin{align*}
P(Z = 1) &= P(X > 0) = 1/2\\
P(Z = 0) &= P(X = 0) = 0\\
P(Z = -1) &= P(X < 0) = 1/2
\end{align*}
using the fact that the $N(0,2)$ distribution is symmetric about zero and continuous. So we see that $Z$ is a [Rademacher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rademacher_distribution) random variable. Now, the question is how does it relate to $Y = X^2$? To answer this question, think about how $Z$ was constructed: it *only* contains information about the sign of $X$. In contrast, $Y$ tells us *nothing* about the sign of $X$. Hence, $Y$ and $Z$ are independent.